# Random image in ImageView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wanted to implement a random image in an imageview in my fragment activity. I am inspired by stack's community question but there was not one for fragment.

Here is the code:

```
    public class OneFragment extends Fragment {
        final Random rnd = new Random();
        ImageView img;

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private static TextView creditWallet;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public static void onUpdateView(Context aiContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (aiContext != null && creditWallet != null)
            creditWallet.setText(PreferenceConnector.readInteger(aiContext, PreferenceConnector.WALLETPOINTS, 0) + "");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
        return view;


        // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...
        final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(2);
        img.setImageDrawable
                (
                        getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                                getApplicationContext()))
                );}


    protected final static int getResourceID
            (final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx) {

        final int ResourceID =ctx.getResources().
                                  getIdentifier(resName, resType,
                                  ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        if (ResourceID == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                    (
                            "No resource string found with name " + resName
                    );
        } else {
            return ResourceID;
        }

    }

}
```

But I've got an error in this line:

```
final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(2);
```

> Unreachable statement

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

After this `return view;` nothing else will be executed so you need to move `return` statement at the end of your `onCreateView` function

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    final ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
//  return view;
//  ^^^^  error remove it 

    // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...
    final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(2);
    img.setImageDrawable
            (
                    getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                            getApplicationContext()))
            );
  return view;
  // ^^^ move it here 
}
```